# Dynamic link not getting generated by selecting two corresponding select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select fields with of which the second is auto filled respect to the value selected in the first select field.

upon selecting a value from the  second select field a link is show which is hidden.

and there is two parts to the javascript one to populate the second select and a jquery that .hide or .show the hidden content

everything works fine with out any error but the second jquery part is not working.

and the jquery version used 1.4.1

below is the link to the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/neo1101/7qo5br6n/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Select Box</title>
<style>
    .immigration-countries-links{
        padding: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
function getOptions(beertype) {
    var list;
    var listValue;
    if (beertype == "Select Region") {
        list = new Array("Select Country");
        listValue = new Array("Select Country");
    }
    if (beertype == "Asia") {
        list = new Array("China","Hong kong","India","Indonesia","Japan","Malaysia","Maldives","Philippines","Singapore","South,Korea","Sri Lanka","Taiwan","Thailand","Vietnam");
        listValue = new Array("china","hong-kong","india","indonesia","japan","malaysia","maldives","philippines","singapore","south-korea","sri-lanka","taiwan","thailand","vietnam");
    }
    if (beertype == "Africa") {
        list = new Array("Mauritius","South Africa");
        listValue = new Array("Mauritius","south-africa");
    }
    if (beertype == "European Union") {
        list = new Array("Austria","Belgium","Bulgaria","Croatia","Cyprus","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","France","Germany","Greece","Hungary","Ireland","Italy","Latvia","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Malta","Netherlands","Poland","Portugal","Romania","Slovakia","Slovenia","Spain","Sweden","United Kingdom");
        listValue = new Array("austria","belgium","bulgaria","croatia","cyprus","denmark","estonia","finland","france","germany","greece","hungary","ireland","italy","latvia","lithuania","luxembourg","malta","netherlands","poland","portugal","romania","slovakia","slovenia","spain","sweden","united-kingdom");
    }
    if (beertype == "Europe") {
        list = new Array("Albania","Armenia","Azerbaijan","Belarus","Bosnia and Herzegovina","Czech Republic","Georgia","Iceland","Kazakhstan","Kyrgyzstan","Liechtenstein","Macedonia","Moldova","Monaco","Montenegro","Norway","Russia","San Marino","Serbia","Switzerland","Tajikistan","Turkey","Ukraine");
        listValue = new Array("albania","armenia","azerbaijan","belarus","bosnia-and-herzegovina","czech-republic","georgia","iceland","kazakhstan","kyrgyzstan","liechtenstein","macedonia","moldova","monaco","montenegro","norway","russia","san-marino","serbia","switzerland","tajikistan","turkey","ukraine");
    }
    if (beertype == "Caribbean") {
        list = new Array("Antigua and Barbuda","Bahamas","Belize","BVI","Cayman Island","Costa Rica","Cuba","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Grenada","Guatemala","Panama","Puerto Rico","Saint Kitts and Nevis Saint Lucia");
        listValue = new Array("antigua-and-barbuda","bahamas","belize","bvi","cayman-island","costa-rica","cuba","dominica","dominican-republic","grenada","guatemala","panama","puerto rico","saint-kitts-and-nevis-saint-lucia");
    }
    if (beertype == "North America") {
        list = new Array("Canada","Mexico","United States");
        listValue = new Array("canada","mexico","united-states");
    }
    if (beertype == "South America") {
        list = new Array("Argentina","Bolivia","Brazil","Chile","Ecuador","Paraguay","Uruguay","Venezuela");
        listValue = new Array("argentina","bolivia","brazil","chile","ecuador","paraguay","uruguay","venezuela");
    }
    if (beertype == "Australian And Oceanic") {
        list = new Array("Australia","Fiji","Marshall Islands","Micronesia","New Zealand","Papua New Guinea","Seychelles","Vanuatu");
        listValue = new Array("australia","fiji","marshall-islands","micronesia","new-zealand","papua-new-guinea","seychelles","vanuatu");
    }
    if (beertype == "Middle East") {
        list = new Array("Bahrain","Kuwait","Qatar","Saudi Arabia","United Arab Emirates","Iran");
        listValue = new Array("bahrain","kuwait","qatar","saudi-arabia","united-arab-emirates","iran");
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < document.OptionMaker.BeerType.length; i++) { //Clear the 2nd menu
        document.OptionMaker.Brand.options[i] = null;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { //Repopulate 2nd menu
        document.OptionMaker.Brand.options[i] = new Option(list[i],listValue[i],0,0);
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="OptionMaker">
  <select name="BeerType" onchange="getOptions(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select Region</option>
    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
    <option value="European Union">European Union</option>
    <option value="Caribbean">Caribbean</option>
    <option value="North America">North America</option>
    <option value="South America">South America</option>
    <option value="Australian And Oceanic">Australian And Oceanic</option>
    <option value="Middle East">Middle East</option>
  </select>
 <select name="Brand" class="">
 <option value="">Select Country</option>
  </select>

<a href="immigration/immigration-albania/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link albania">Albania</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-antigua-and-barbuda/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link antigua-and-Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-antigua-and-barbuda/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link argentina">Argentina</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-armenia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link armenia">Armenia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-australia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link australia">Australia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-austria/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link austria">Austria</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-azerbaijan/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-bahamas/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link bahamas">Bahamas</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-bahrain/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link bahrain">Bahrain</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-belarus/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link Belarus">Belarus</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-belgium/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link belgium">Belgium</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-belize/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link belize">Belize</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-bolivia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link Bolivia">Bolivia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-bosnia-and-herzegovina/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link bosnia-and-herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-brazil/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link brazil">Brazil</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-bulgaria/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link bulgaria"></a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-bvi/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link">BVI</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-canada/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link">Canada</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-cayman-island/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link cayman-island">Cayman Island</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-chile/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link chile">Chile</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-china/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link china">China</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-costa-rica/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link costa-rica">Costa Rica</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-croatia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link croatia">Croatia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-cuba/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link cuba">Cuba</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-cyprus/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link cyprus">Cyprus</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-czech-republic/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link czech-republic">Czech Republic</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-denmark/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link denmark">Denmark</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-dominica/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link dominica">Dominica</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-dominican-republic/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link dominican-republic">Dominican Republic</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-ecuador/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link ecuador">Ecuador</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-estonia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link estonia">Estonia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-fiji/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link fiji">Fiji</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-finland/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link finland">Finland</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-france/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link france">France</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-georgia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link georgia">Georgia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-germany/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link germany">Germany</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-greece/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link greece">Greece</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-grenada/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link grenada">Grenada</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-guatemala/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link guatemala">Guatemala</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-hong-kong/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link hong-kong">Hong Kong</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-hungary/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link hungary">Hungary</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-iceland/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link iceland">Iceland</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-india/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link india">India</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-indonesia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link indonesia">Indonesia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-ireland/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link ireland">Ireland</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-italy/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link italy">Italy</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-japan/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link japan">Japan</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-kazakhstan/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-kuwait/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link kuwait">Kuwait</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-kyrgyzstan/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-latvia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link latvia">Latvia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-liechtenstein/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-lithuania/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link lithuania">Lithuania</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-luxembourg/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link luxembourg">Luxembourg</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-macedonia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link macedonia">Macedonia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-malaysia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link malaysia">Malaysia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-maldives/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link maldives">Maldives</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-malta/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link malta">Malta</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-marshall-islands/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link marshall-islands">Marshall Islands</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-mauritius/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link mauritius">Mauritius</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-mexico/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link meixco">Mexico</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-micronesia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link micronesia">Micronesia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-moldova/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link moldova">Moldova</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-monaco/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link monaco">Monaco</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-montenegro/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link montenegro">Montenegro</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-netherlands/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link netherlands">Netherlands</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-new-zealand/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link new-zealand">New Zealand</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-norway/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link norway">Norway</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-panama/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link panama">Panama</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-papua-new-guinea/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link papua-new-guinea">Papua New Guinea</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-paraguay/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link paraguay">Paraguay</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-philippines/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link philippines">Philippines</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-poland/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link poland">Poland</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-portugal/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link portugal">Portugal</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-puerto-rico/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link puerto-rico">Puerto Rico</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-qatar/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link qatar">Qatar</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-romania/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link romania">Romania</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-russia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link russia">Russia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-saint-kitts-and-nevis/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link saint-kitts-and-nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-saint-lucia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link saint-lucia">Saint Lucia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-san-marino/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link san-marino">San Marino</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-saudi-arabia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link saudi-arabia">Saudi Arabia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-serbia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link serbia">Serbia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-seychelles/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link seychelles">Seychelles</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-singapore/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link singapore">Singapore</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-slovakia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link slovakia">Slovakia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-slovenia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link slovenia">Slovenia</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-south-africa/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link south-africa">South Africa</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-south-korea/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link south-korea">South Korea</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-spain/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link spain">Spain</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-sri-lanka/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link sri-lanka">Sri Lanka</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-sweden/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link sweden">Sweden</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-switzerland/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link switzerland">Switzerland</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-taiwan/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link taiwan">Taiwan</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-tajikistan/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link tajikistan">Tajikistan</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-thailand/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link thailand">Thailand</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-turkey/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link turkey">Turkey</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-ukraine/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link ukraine">Ukraine</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-united-arab-emirates/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link united-arab-emirates">United Arab Emirates</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-united-kingdom/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link united-kingdom">United Kingdom</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-united-states/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link united-states">United States</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-uruguay/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link uruguay">Uruguay</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-vanuatu/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link vanuatu">Vanuatu</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-venezuela/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link venezuela">Venezuela</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-vietnam/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link vietnam">Vietnam</a> 
<a href="immigration/immigration-iran/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link iran">Iran</a> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".immigration-countries-links").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".immigration-countries-links").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".immigration-countries-links").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
</form></body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: All those `if`s - you might want to discover `switch()` :)

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of using new Array() use simply [...]  for representing array.

Comment: both of the suggestions are taken.. Thank you...  but why would'nt the second party work that un-hides the link

Comment: checkout the jsfiddle... to get the idea

Comment: Do you mind if I simplify your code a bit in my answer? Also, does it _have_ to be jQuery?

Comment: @SudarshanPillai please check my answer and run the included code snippet to see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because at the `change` code, you don't pass the `select` field, but you pass the links class name `immigration-countries-links`. You need to pass the countries select the the `change` event so for it to work. I have also added a `change` to the `regions` select to trigger a `change` on `#countries` select so to have it populate the first country link when you change the region.

Please run the below snippet (*I also have changed your jQuery version to `3.4.1` because `1.4.1` is very outdated*):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // I have set the countries select to have an ID of countries
    // so, we use that here
    $("#countries").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".immigration-countries-links").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".immigration-countries-links").hide();
            }
        });
    });
    
    // Also trigger change event when regions select changes
    $("#regions").change(function() {
      $("#countries").trigger("change");
    });
});

function getOptions(beertype) {
  var list;
  var listValue;
  if (beertype == "Select Region") {
    list = new Array("Select Country");
    listValue = new Array("Select Country");
  }
  if (beertype == "Asia") {
    list = new Array("China","Hong kong","India","Indonesia","Japan","Malaysia","Maldives","Philippines","Singapore","South,Korea","Sri Lanka","Taiwan","Thailand","Vietnam");
    listValue = new Array("china","hong-kong","india","indonesia","japan","malaysia","maldives","philippines","singapore","south-korea","sri-lanka","taiwan","thailand","vietnam");
  }
  if (beertype == "Africa") {
    list = new Array("Mauritius","South Africa");
    listValue = new Array("Mauritius","south-africa");
  }
  if (beertype == "European Union") {
    list = new Array("Austria","Belgium","Bulgaria","Croatia","Cyprus","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","France","Germany","Greece","Hungary","Ireland","Italy","Latvia","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Malta","Netherlands","Poland","Portugal","Romania","Slovakia","Slovenia","Spain","Sweden","United Kingdom");
    listValue = new Array("austria","belgium","bulgaria","croatia","cyprus","denmark","estonia","finland","france","germany","greece","hungary","ireland","italy","latvia","lithuania","luxembourg","malta","netherlands","poland","portugal","romania","slovakia","slovenia","spain","sweden","united-kingdom");
  }
  if (beertype == "Europe") {
    list = new Array("Albania","Armenia","Azerbaijan","Belarus","Bosnia and Herzegovina","Czech Republic","Georgia","Iceland","Kazakhstan","Kyrgyzstan","Liechtenstein","Macedonia","Moldova","Monaco","Montenegro","Norway","Russia","San Marino","Serbia","Switzerland","Tajikistan","Turkey","Ukraine");
    listValue = new Array("albania","armenia","azerbaijan","belarus","bosnia-and-herzegovina","czech-republic","georgia","iceland","kazakhstan","kyrgyzstan","liechtenstein","macedonia","moldova","monaco","montenegro","norway","russia","san-marino","serbia","switzerland","tajikistan","turkey","ukraine");
  }
  if (beertype == "Caribbean") {
    list = new Array("Antigua and Barbuda","Bahamas","Belize","BVI","Cayman Island","Costa Rica","Cuba","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Grenada","Guatemala","Panama","Puerto Rico","Saint Kitts and Nevis Saint Lucia");
    listValue = new Array("antigua-and-barbuda","bahamas","belize","bvi","cayman-island","costa-rica","cuba","dominica","dominican-republic","grenada","guatemala","panama","puerto rico","saint-kitts-and-nevis-saint-lucia");
  }
  if (beertype == "North America") {
    list = new Array("Canada","Mexico","United States");
    listValue = new Array("canada","mexico","united-states");
  }
  if (beertype == "South America") {
    list = new Array("Argentina","Bolivia","Brazil","Chile","Ecuador","Paraguay","Uruguay","Venezuela");
    listValue = new Array("argentina","bolivia","brazil","chile","ecuador","paraguay","uruguay","venezuela");
  }
  if (beertype == "Australian And Oceanic") {
    list = new Array("Australia","Fiji","Marshall Islands","Micronesia","New Zealand","Papua New Guinea","Seychelles","Vanuatu");
    listValue = new Array("australia","fiji","marshall-islands","micronesia","new-zealand","papua-new-guinea","seychelles","vanuatu");
  }
  if (beertype == "Middle East") {
    list = new Array("Bahrain","Kuwait","Qatar","Saudi Arabia","United Arab Emirates","Iran");
    listValue = new Array("bahrain","kuwait","qatar","saudi-arabia","united-arab-emirates","iran");
  }
  
  $(document.OptionMaker.Brand).empty();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < document.OptionMaker.BeerType.length; i++) { //Clear the 2nd menu
    document.OptionMaker.Brand.options[i] = null;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { //Repopulate 2nd menu
    document.OptionMaker.Brand.options[i] = new Option(list[i],listValue[i],0,0);
  }
}
```

```css
.immigration-countries-links{
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<form name="OptionMaker">

<select id="regions" name="BeerType" onchange="getOptions(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select Region</option>
  <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
  <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
  <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
  <option value="European Union">European Union</option>
  <option value="Caribbean">Caribbean</option>
  <option value="North America">North America</option>
  <option value="South America">South America</option>
  <option value="Australian And Oceanic">Australian And Oceanic</option>
  <option value="Middle East">Middle East</option>
</select>
<select id="countries" name="Brand" class="">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
</select>

<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-albania/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link albania">Albania</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-antigua-and-barbuda/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link antigua-and-Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-antigua-and-barbuda/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link argentina">Argentina</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-armenia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link armenia">Armenia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-australia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link australia">Australia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-austria/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link austria">Austria</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-azerbaijan/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-bahamas/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link bahamas">Bahamas</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-bahrain/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link bahrain">Bahrain</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-belarus/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link Belarus">Belarus</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-belgium/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link belgium">Belgium</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-belize/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link belize">Belize</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-bolivia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link Bolivia">Bolivia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-bosnia-and-herzegovina/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link bosnia-and-herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-brazil/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link brazil">Brazil</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-bulgaria/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link bulgaria"></a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-bvi/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link">BVI</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-canada/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link">Canada</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-cayman-island/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link cayman-island">Cayman Island</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-chile/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link chile">Chile</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-china/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link china">China</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-costa-rica/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link costa-rica">Costa Rica</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-croatia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link croatia">Croatia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-cuba/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link cuba">Cuba</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-cyprus/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link cyprus">Cyprus</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-czech-republic/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link czech-republic">Czech Republic</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-denmark/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link denmark">Denmark</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-dominica/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link dominica">Dominica</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-dominican-republic/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link dominican-republic">Dominican Republic</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-ecuador/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link ecuador">Ecuador</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-estonia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link estonia">Estonia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-fiji/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link fiji">Fiji</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-finland/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link finland">Finland</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-france/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link france">France</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-georgia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link georgia">Georgia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-germany/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link germany">Germany</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-greece/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link greece">Greece</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-grenada/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link grenada">Grenada</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-guatemala/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link guatemala">Guatemala</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-hong-kong/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link hong-kong">Hong Kong</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-hungary/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link hungary">Hungary</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-iceland/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link iceland">Iceland</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-india/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link india">India</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-indonesia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link indonesia">Indonesia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-ireland/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link ireland">Ireland</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-italy/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link italy">Italy</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-japan/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link japan">Japan</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-kazakhstan/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-kuwait/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link kuwait">Kuwait</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-kyrgyzstan/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-latvia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link latvia">Latvia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-liechtenstein/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-lithuania/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link lithuania">Lithuania</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-luxembourg/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link luxembourg">Luxembourg</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-macedonia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link macedonia">Macedonia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-malaysia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link malaysia">Malaysia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-maldives/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link maldives">Maldives</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-malta/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link malta">Malta</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-marshall-islands/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link marshall-islands">Marshall Islands</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-mauritius/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link mauritius">Mauritius</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-mexico/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link meixco">Mexico</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-micronesia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link micronesia">Micronesia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-moldova/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link moldova">Moldova</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-monaco/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link monaco">Monaco</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-montenegro/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link montenegro">Montenegro</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-netherlands/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link netherlands">Netherlands</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-new-zealand/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link new-zealand">New Zealand</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-norway/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link norway">Norway</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-panama/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link panama">Panama</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-papua-new-guinea/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link papua-new-guinea">Papua New Guinea</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-paraguay/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link paraguay">Paraguay</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-philippines/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link philippines">Philippines</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-poland/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link poland">Poland</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-portugal/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link portugal">Portugal</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-puerto-rico/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link puerto-rico">Puerto Rico</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-qatar/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link qatar">Qatar</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-romania/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link romania">Romania</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-russia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link russia">Russia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-saint-kitts-and-nevis/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link saint-kitts-and-nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-saint-lucia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link saint-lucia">Saint Lucia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-san-marino/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link san-marino">San Marino</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-saudi-arabia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link saudi-arabia">Saudi Arabia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-serbia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link serbia">Serbia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-seychelles/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link seychelles">Seychelles</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-singapore/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link singapore">Singapore</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-slovakia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link slovakia">Slovakia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-slovenia/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link slovenia">Slovenia</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-south-africa/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link south-africa">South Africa</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-south-korea/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link south-korea">South Korea</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-spain/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link spain">Spain</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-sri-lanka/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link sri-lanka">Sri Lanka</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-sweden/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link sweden">Sweden</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-switzerland/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link switzerland">Switzerland</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-taiwan/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link taiwan">Taiwan</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-tajikistan/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link tajikistan">Tajikistan</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-thailand/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link thailand">Thailand</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-turkey/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link turkey">Turkey</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-ukraine/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link ukraine">Ukraine</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-united-arab-emirates/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link united-arab-emirates">United Arab Emirates</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-united-kingdom/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link united-kingdom">United Kingdom</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-united-states/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link united-states">United States</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-uruguay/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link uruguay">Uruguay</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-vanuatu/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link vanuatu">Vanuatu</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-venezuela/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link venezuela">Venezuela</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-vietnam/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link vietnam">Vietnam</a> 
<a href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-iran/" class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link iran">Iran</a>
```

Comment: Perfect........ awesome dude.... Right on target .... Thank you so much ... cheers

Comment: i notice some thing weird .. when we check for a region and go to the next condition some of the countries form the old list gets populated in the like say Asian countries in africa. Y is this happening

Comment: Just run `$(document.OptionMaker.Brand).empty();` inside `getOptions` function before the `for` loops to clear the options. Check my updated answer and code snippet. **EDIT** The answer you accepted, leaves the previous selected country when you change region.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative version of the accepted answer. It uses jQuery and on change event listeners. I've also converted the lists into a JS object for easier reading.

```js
const optionList = {
    "Select Region": {
    list: [
            "Select Country"
        ],
    listValue: [
            "Select Country"
        ]
    },
    "Asia": {
    list: [
            "China",
            "Hong kong",
            "India",
            "Indonesia",
            "Japan",
            "Malaysia",
            "Maldives",
            "Philippines",
            "Singapore",
            "South,Korea",
            "Sri Lanka",
            "Taiwan",
            "Thailand",
            "Vietnam"
        ],
    listValue: [
            "china",
            "hong-kong",
            "india",
            "indonesia",
            "japan",
            "malaysia",
            "maldives",
            "philippines",
            "singapore",
            "south-korea",
            "sri-lanka",
            "taiwan",
            "thailand",
            "vietnam"
        ]
    },
    "Africa": {
    list: [
            "Mauritius",
            "South Africa"
        ],
    listValue: [
            "Mauritius",
            "south-africa"
        ]
    },
    "European Union": {
    list: [
            "Austria",
            "Belgium",
            "Bulgaria",
            "Croatia",
            "Cyprus",
            "Denmark",
            "Estonia",
            "Finland",
            "France",
            "Germany",
            "Greece",
            "Hungary",
            "Ireland",
            "Italy",
            "Latvia",
            "Lithuania",
            "Luxembourg",
            "Malta",
            "Netherlands",
            "Poland",
            "Portugal",
            "Romania",
            "Slovakia",
            "Slovenia",
            "Spain",
            "Sweden",
            "United Kingdom"
        ],
    listValue: [
            "austria",
            "belgium",
            "bulgaria",
            "croatia",
            "cyprus",
            "denmark",
            "estonia",
            "finland",
            "france",
            "germany",
            "greece",
            "hungary",
            "ireland",
            "italy",
            "latvia",
            "lithuania",
            "luxembourg",
            "malta",
            "netherlands",
            "poland",
            "portugal",
            "romania",
            "slovakia",
            "slovenia",
            "spain",
            "sweden",
            "united-kingdom"
        ]
    },
    "Europe": {
    list: [
            "Albania",
            "Armenia",
            "Azerbaijan",
            "Belarus",
            "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
            "Czech Republic",
            "Georgia",
            "Iceland",
            "Kazakhstan",
            "Kyrgyzstan",
            "Liechtenstein",
            "Macedonia",
            "Moldova",
            "Monaco",
            "Montenegro",
            "Norway",
            "Russia",
            "San Marino",
            "Serbia",
            "Switzerland",
            "Tajikistan",
            "Turkey",
            "Ukraine"
        ],
    listValue: [
            "albania",
            "armenia",
            "azerbaijan",
            "belarus",
            "bosnia-and-herzegovina",
            "czech-republic",
            "georgia",
            "iceland",
            "kazakhstan",
            "kyrgyzstan",
            "liechtenstein",
            "macedonia",
            "moldova",
            "monaco",
            "montenegro",
            "norway",
            "russia",
            "san-marino",
            "serbia",
            "switzerland",
            "tajikistan",
            "turkey",
            "ukraine"
        ]
    },
    "Caribbean": {
    list: [
            "Antigua and Barbuda",
            "Bahamas",
            "Belize",
            "BVI",
            "Cayman Island",
            "Costa Rica",
            "Cuba",
            "Dominica",
            "Dominican Republic",
            "Grenada",
            "Guatemala",
            "Panama",
            "Puerto Rico",
            "Saint Kitts and Nevis Saint Lucia"
        ],
    listValue: [
            "antigua-and-barbuda",
            "bahamas",
            "belize",
            "bvi",
            "cayman-island",
            "costa-rica",
            "cuba",
            "dominica",
            "dominican-republic",
            "grenada",
            "guatemala",
            "panama",
            "puerto rico",
            "saint-kitts-and-nevis-saint-lucia"
        ]
    },
    "North America": {
    list: [
            "Canada",
            "Mexico",
            "United States"
        ],
    listValue: [
            "canada",
            "mexico",
            "united-states"
        ]
    },
    "South America": {
    list: [
            "Argentina",
            "Bolivia",
            "Brazil",
            "Chile",
            "Ecuador",
            "Paraguay",
            "Uruguay",
            "Venezuela"
        ],
    listValue: [
            "argentina",
            "bolivia",
            "brazil",
            "chile",
            "ecuador",
            "paraguay",
            "uruguay",
            "venezuela"
        ]
    },
    "Australian and Oceanic": {
    list: [
            "Australia",
            "Fiji",
            "Marshall Islands",
            "Micronesia",
            "New Zealand",
            "Papua New Guinea",
            "Seychelles",
            "Vanuatu"
        ],
    listValue: [
            "australia",
            "fiji",
            "marshall-islands",
            "micronesia",
            "new-zealand",
            "papua-new-guinea",
            "seychelles",
            "vanuatu"
        ]
    },
    "Middle East": {
    list: [
            "Bahrain",
            "Kuwait",
            "Qatar",
            "Saudi Arabia",
            "United Arab Emirates",
            "Iran"
        ],
    listValue: [
            "bahrain",
            "kuwait",
            "qatar",
            "saudi-arabia",
            "united-arab-emirates",
            "iran"
        ]
    }
};

$("select[name='Brand']").change(function() {
  $("#linkBox").html(
    `<a 
        href="https://www.millionmakers.com/immigration/immigration-${$('select[name="Brand"]').val()}/"
        class="immigration-countries-links btn-country-link ${$('select[name="Brand"]').val()}">
            ${$('select[name="Brand"] option:selected').text()}
        </a>`
  );
});

$("select[name='BeerType']").change(function() {
  const beertype = $("select[name='BeerType']").val();
  let list = optionList[beertype].list;
  let listValue = optionList[beertype].listValue;

  const BrandBox = $("select[name='Brand']");
  const linkBox = $("#linkbox");

  // Using jQuery, empty the select box
  BrandBox.empty();

  // Prepare options
  let options = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    options += `<option value="${listValue[i]}">${list[i]}</option>`;
    }
    // Add options to Brand box
  BrandBox.append(options);
});
```

```css
.immigration-countries-links {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Select Box</title>

</head>

<body>
  <form name="OptionMaker">
    <select name="BeerType">
      <option value="">Select Region</option>
      <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
      <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
      <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
      <option value="European Union">European Union</option>
      <option value="Caribbean">Caribbean</option>
      <option value="North America">North America</option>
      <option value="South America">South America</option>
      <option value="Australian And Oceanic">Australian And Oceanic</option>
      <option value="Middle East">Middle East</option>
    </select>
    <select name="Brand" class="">
      <option value="">Select Country</option>
    </select>

    <span id="linkBox"></span>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Its good. Can the link generation be a little more dynamic. can the previously generated link hide when we start to check for the next match case.

Comment: Yes it does. The link is removed and a new link is created in its place.